# Set text to jlabel doesn't change the text

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a banking application where the user creates an account and can deposit, withdraw, transfer and view their balance. My problem is with the view balance part because I want it to display the balance and it doesn't. I have a database connected and after the user clicks the "Show balance" button it should display their amount. Below is my code and an image of what is shows. Can someone help me to fix it please?

```
package app;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ViewBalance extends JFrame {

    private JLabel mainl, balance;
    private JButton ok;
    ResultSet result = null;

    public ViewBalance(Statement statement, int accnum) { //accnum is the account number that was just created
        super("Banking Application");

        mainl = new JLabel("Balance", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        balance = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ok = new JButton("Ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT balance FROM CardInfo WHERE accnum = " + accnum + ";");
                    if (result.next()) {
                        System.out.println(result.getInt(1));
                        balance.setText("Your balance is " + result.getInt(1));
                        balance.setVisible(true); 
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                dispose();
                new MainFrame(statement, accnum).setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        add(mainl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(balance, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

here is also my sql code

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS BankingApplication;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CardInfo CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AccountInfo CASCADE;

CREATE DATABASE BankingApplication
    WITH
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1253'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1253'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False;
    
CREATE TABLE AccountInfo(
    accnum INT,
    fname varchar(100),
    lname varchar(100),
    mobile varchar(10),
    id varchar(20),
    ssn varchar(9),
    address varchar(100),
    email varchar(100),
    password varchar(100),
    primary key(accnum)
);

CREATE TABLE CardInfo(
    accnum int,
    cardnum varchar(16),
    expmonth int,
    expyear int,
    cvv int,
    pin int,
    balance float,
    primary key(cardnum),
    FOREIGN KEY (accnum) REFERENCES AccountInfo (accnum)
);



SELECT * FROM AccountInfo;
SELECT * FROM CardInfo;
```

[this is the image I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ51V.png)
[this is the image it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyvTG.png)

I have tried to change the balance jlabel on what to display
I have tried changing the sql statement but non of these work. It is like the balance.setText() in the ActionListener is not working

Comment: So, you execute the query, if it has a row, you set the labels text, you then dispose/close the frame so I’m at a lose to figure out how you expect to see the result

Comment: ah yes! I get my mistake. never occured to me. thank you very much @MadProgrammer

Comment: Ok, so you have a layout issue because a label with no text has zero size - so, maybe set the initial text to something like “0”. Alternatively, you can call pack on the frame to force it to change size to fit the new text

Comment: I changed it and added the sql statement to the previous JFrame so when they click on the view balance button to find the balance and then when I initialize the jlabel it has the correct amount. thank you again @MadProgrammer. you were very helpful!!